# StackNavigator vs createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm upgrading my app from react-navigation 1.5 to 3.0.9.
I'm not clear what are the difference in component state management, but I'm sure there are some. This used to works fine, now it behavies weird. It looks like the state is cached somehow and, browsing around and coming back to this component, `state.params.letter` is still the same, even when I don't need that. Shouldn't the state be destroyed if I change view?

The component have a very simple logic, it show a `FlatList` of items. If the prop `letter` is present, it shows just the items that starts with that letter.

```
export default class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    DB = null;
    componentDidMount(){
        //check for the param "letter"
        let L = this.props.navigation.state.params ? this.props.navigation.state.params.letter : null;
        this.setState({
            DB: L ? this.DB.getStartWith(L) : this.DB.getAll()
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const { t, i18n, navigation } = this.props;


        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList data={this.state.DB}
                    renderItem=({item}) => <Text> {item} </Text>
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way a react-navigation stack navigator works, it stores the stack of different screens so that when you it the back button it knows which screen you last visited. When you pass a parameter like in your case:

```js
this.props.navigation.state.params.letter
```

**The state gets stored in the react navigation stack and will stay there until you 'destroy' your screen** (for example going back from that screen), for example if your stack looks like (screen1 > search) and then you move to screen2 so that it becomes (screen1 > search > screen2) **the internal state of the search component will be destroyed but not the react navigation state**, so if you go back the parameter letter will be the same, the only way to destroy that parameter is to go back to screen1. An alternative is to store your letter parameter **using something like redux**, in general I try to avoid passing variables using the react-navigation params, unless it's a parameter related to the navigation itself (like navigation options).